# Drop down list item with </a> tag is not shown

Tags: html, asp.net, dropdown

My drop down list has the following code:

```
<div id="dropdown" style="display:none; color:white;">
                     <div class="dropdownlist"><a href="Discussion_page.aspx">Discussion Page</a></div>
                     <div class="dropdownlist" style="display:none"><a href="MyAccount.aspx">My Account</a></div>
                     <div class="dropdownlist" id= "login" onclick="login();>Login</div>
                     <div class="dropdownlist" id= "logout" runat="server"><a href="logout.aspx">Logout</a></div>
                 </div>
```

when I click a certain button the property none is changed to block. But it doesn't show the login option. My account option is understandable since it is hidden but why login option is not shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are missing quote near onclick property. Please see the screenshot for more details.[image]

I have fixed it for you

```html
<div id="dropdown" style="display:block; color:black;">
                     <div class="dropdownlist"><a href="Discussion_page.aspx">Discussion Page</a></div>
                     <div class="dropdownlist" style="display:none"><a href="MyAccount.aspx">My Account</a></div>
                     <div class="dropdownlist" id= "login" onclick="login();">Login</div>
                     <div class="dropdownlist" id= "logout" runat="server"><a href="logout.aspx">Logout</a></div>
                 </div>
```

Comment: Yes, it is a mistake, but it's not the reason since I changed it, and nothing happened

Comment: yes, but after update it it's visible on the screen, but you just because you define the color 'white' so it mashed with background and its seen not visible.

Comment: Sorry for my english. :( Simply you need to change the color

Comment: Yes, it works! wow! Thanks.. Now it feels a silly mistake. Your English is absolutely okay.

Answer (score 0):

Your login option doesn't have an a tag.

```
<div class="dropdownlist" id= "login" onclick="login()">Login</div>
```

And I also fixed an error there for you.